# How do I subscribe to weekly newsletter?

Tags: discussion, support, features

I have subscribed to weekly newsletter of SO & Mathematica, but I don't see such option is CS forum. Is there any to know best questions of the week ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not on the home page, but when you open any question it's there:

[image]